# Google actions no webhook call on account unlinking

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, actions-on-google

I'm working on a google assistant integration where I see some limitation with google when it comes to account unlinking. When we unlink the account from simulator settings it only unlinks at the google end, google doesn't do any webhook call to notify the host where the webhook is hosted, this leaves the account linked at the server end. I'm expecting a webhook call from google on unlink so the accounts can be unlinked at my host too.
Wanted to check if anyone has faced this problem and have any other alternate for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your webhook for conversational actions does not get called when a user unlinks their account. When that user activates your Action again, your webhook will not get any linking status and will interpret them as a user who has never linked their account before.

Comment: yes I throughly understand this but, this behavior leaves the account linked at the hosting end even though the account is unlinked at google end, I was trying to address this problem. I'm trying to understand if there is any alternate solution from google end for this.

Answer (score 0):

While the Actions webhook won't deliver the information you're looking for, you may wish to look into [Cross Account Protection](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc) for the Google Account.

Under this scheme you're setting up another endpoint that gets alerts for certain ["events"](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#supported_event_types) against the original account. These can include a token revocation event and an account purged event, either of which might be sent when the account is unlinked.